# How create a service correctly?

Tags: linux, script, centos, shell-script, services

Here it's what I do:

1) create an user `some_deployer` 
2) then create a folder to script like `/company/script/<service name>`  
3) in this folder I create the `start.sh` and `stop.sh` scripts and give the ownership to the user `some_deployer` and the permission with `chmod 755`. 
4) then after create the script in `/etc/init.d/` folder, like `<service name>-service` and give the ownership to the user `some_deployer` and the permission with `chmod 755` too.
5) then add this service to the list of services, still inside of the `/etc/init.d/` with

/sbin/chkconfig --add -service (suse)
or
update-rc.d `<service name>` defaults (ubuntu)

Is this correct ? Is this the best way to proceed it ?
I'm asking 'cause suddenly one of my service that I'm creating is not working anymore, I'm trying the command /etc/init.d/-service and it says that the `command is not found`, why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't necessary to create a user, but you certainly can if its to your advantage. not sure what your talking about with /company/script/, but no reason not to. just make sure that your script file is in /etc/init.d before running update-rc.d. I'm not sure why you want to use /company/script/ but from your error, your service name is not coming through.

Look into the LSB specs for an init.d script here:http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts 
you create a single script with the capabilities stop/start/restart/force-reload/status, and then register it with update-rc.d or whatever as you have suggested. that will allow update-rc.d to point to a single file, but perform all the required operations using it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't believe LSB too much, most distributions have long abandoned `sysvinit`, Ubuntu, RHEL use `upstart` (in RHEL's case mostly in SysV compatibility mode), Fedora is using `systemd` for more than a year now, in Fedora 18 almost all services are native systemd. One of systemd's promises is to continue handling LSB-compatible setups, but it offers many advantages if using the native configuration. Take a look at its extensive [documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd).